# View Public Key in Domain Key for a Domain

Tags: nslookup

Using Jeff's [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) I'm creating domain keys for my account. I wanted to verify the setup using Get or Host command with Bind for Windows but I'm lost one of the commands. I can see view the _domainkey. txt file with this command:

```
host -t txt _domainkey.stackoverflow.com
```

but I'm at a loss at how I'd find the selector record. Jeff points out it can be anything before the before the period in "._domainkey.domain.com" but how would I list all records if I didn't know the exact query name? Is there a wildcard I could use to view all TXT or all records under this section?

Answer (score 1):

> how would I list all records if I didn't know the exact query name?

The selector is defined on your mail server or client. Someone(something) receiving a message would know what selector to look up because it will be part of the DKIM-Signature header of the message, specifically it is the "s=" tag.

Since this is your own zone you could do a zone transfer or just examine the zone database directly to see what you have set.

See [RFC 4871](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4871)

- 3.1 Selectors https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4871#section-3.1
- 5.7 DKIM-Signature Header field https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4871#section-5.7